# Как реализовать открытие, обновление данных и его завершение, сохранение и закрытие файла

Tags: excel, vba

Есть функция, которая открывает по очереди все файлы в заданной папке,
обновляет данные, сохраняет и закрывает.
Файл действительно открывается и сохраняется, а вот обновиться данные,
по всей видимости, не успевают, т.к. файл закрывается.
Как решение видится проверка закончилось ли обновление данных.
Но как это реализовать? Возможно есть другое решение.

```
Sub Obnovlenie_Sokhranenie_failov_v_papke()
Dim s As String, fldr As String, j As Integer, f As Integer
Dim rc As Range
fldr = "d:\"
s = Dir(fldr & "*.xls*")
j = 0
f = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'podschyot kolichestva failov v papke
Do While s <> ""
    s = Dir
    f = f + 1
Loop

'obrabotka failov v papke
s = Dir(fldr & "*.xls*")
Do While s <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(fldr & s)
        'deistviia s knigoi
        .RefreshAll
        .Save
        .Close (True)
    End With
    s = Dir
    j = j + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Obrabotano: " & j & " iz " & f & " failov" & " -> " & s: DoEvents
Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.StatusBar = "Obrabotano: " & j & " èç " & f & " failov"

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В *VBA* нет распараллеливания вычислений - пока выполняется код, другие действия выполнить нельзя (если это не разрешено в коде). В случае с обновлением связей - по логике: пока обновление не закончено, макрос дальше не работает. Возможно, не успевают пересчитаться формулы или во внутренней кухне не все на место поставлено...

Советы на уровне догадок.

Попробуйте поработать с задержкой сохранения и закрытия книги:

```
    .RefreshAll
    Application.Wait Time:=Now + TimeValue("0:00:04") ' задержка'
    .Save:.Close
```

Если не помогло, попробовать использовать (ну очень уж нелепая догадка) прерывания (передачу управления)

```
.RefreshAll
DoEvents
```

Да, непонятно, какие связи в книге... Вместо (или вместе с) *.RefreshAll* обновить все связи

```
.UpdateLink Name:=.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Больше мыслей по этому поводу нет.

Дополните код отключением/включением *Application.DisplayAlerts* -  от *Excel* не будет лишних вопросов.

Comment: Все равно и даже с большими (20-30 с) задержками обновление не происходит. Открывает, ждет, сохраняет, но не обновляет.

Comment: Еще дополнил ответ

Comment: Всё равно не помогает.

Comment: Попробую другим путем.
Например открывать файлы, как и раньше, но запускать в каждом из них макрос.

Comment: В каждом файле в Module1 есть макрос UpdateFile.
Как его запускать с помощью команды Application.Run ?

Comment: Причина непонятна и проблема остается нерешенной. А по запуску кода -это другая тема.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если не очень секретно и связей не слишком много - пришлите файл, который не обновляется, и связанные файлы, на почту. Попрбую решить проблему

Comment: Отправил на почту пример.