# Макрос, который обновит запрос, а после завершения переключится на определенный лист

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Есть 2 файла excel 2016, в первом заполняю "умные" таблицы и выгружаю во второй где строится сводная таблица.

Задача: Сделать макрос который обновит запрос, дождется завершения а после обновит все сводные таблицы.

Код макроса обновления запроса и сводных таблиц:

```
IsBG_Refresh = ThisWorkbook.Connections("Запрос — AllTables").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Запрос — AllTables").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Запрос — AllTables").Refresh
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Запрос — AllTables").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = IsBG_Refresh
Sheets("Статистика").PivotTables("Статистика").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Сравнение").PivotTables("Сравнение").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Диаграмма").PivotTables("Диаграмма").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Статистика").Range("H1").Value = 1
```

Код запуска другого макроса(прописан в лист Статистика):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Address = "$H$1" Then
     If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
        If Range("H1") = 1 Then
    Call ActivateStatList
     End If
      End If
End Sub
```

Код макроса который должен активировать первый лист:

```
Sub ActivateStatList()
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
Sheets("Статистика").Activate
Sheets("Статистика").Range("H1").Clear
End Sub
```

Все работает только после обновление запроса перекидывает на страницу с "умной" таблицей и автоматически ее выделяет. Сколько бы добавлял ожидание после выполнение обновления все равно в конце макроса он выделяют эту таблицу, даже добавление второго макроса не помогло. Добавление запроса в модель данных не вариант так как тогда исчезает возможность добавить вычисляемое поле, добавить вычисление в самом запросе тоже не вариант так как итого считается не верно.

Answer (score 0):

Макрос обновления запроса и сводных таблиц меняет значение листа:

```
Sheets("Статистика").Range("H1").Value = 1
```

При этом срабатывает событие листа *Статистика*, в коде которого - вызов макроса `ActivateStatList`

```
If Range("H1") = 1 Then Call ActivateStatList
```

В коде активации другого листа есть интересная строчка:

```
Sheets("Статистика").Range("H1").Clear
```

Чем интересна? Изменение значения ячейки опять вызывает срабатывание макроса события листа *Статистика*...

Вопрос. Зачем реагировать на события и вызывать дополнительные пересчеты?

В процедуре обновления запроса убираем строку:

```
Sheets("Статистика").Range("H1").Value = 1
```

Вместо нее:

```
Call ActivateStatList
```

Убираем лишнее и из этого кода:

```
Sub ActivateStatList()
     Sheets("Статистика").Activate
End Sub
```

Или добавляем строчку в первый (и единственный) макрос:

```
    With ThisWorkbook.Connections("Запрос — AllTables")
        IsBG_Refresh = .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery
        .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        .Refresh
        .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = IsBG_Refresh
    End With

    Sheets("Сравнение").PivotTables("Сравнение").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("Диаграмма").PivotTables("Диаграмма").PivotCache.Refresh

    With Sheets("Статистика")
        .PivotTables("Статистика").PivotCache.Refresh
        .Activate
    End With
```

Comment: Он выделяет эту таблицу после завершение макроса, подумал что если добавлю пару действий после него то он выделит свою таблицу, а второй макрос запустится уже после выделение и вернет на нужный лист. Вставил ваш вариант (как с Call ActivateStatList, так и вариант с одним макросом) результат тот же

Comment: Попробуйте комментировать запрос и прогнать код. Если сработает - что-то с запросом. Был похожий вопрос, не решили. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893507/Как-реализовать-открытие-обновление-данных-и-его-завершение-сохранение-и-закры

Comment: "Попробуйте комментировать запрос" не понял эту часть. С запросом вроде все ок, проверил на других запросах из других книг, он всегда переходит на таблицу которую обновил, он так не делает если обновляет подключение из SQL базы(другие не проверял) а не запрос из книги хотя в обоих случаях данные загружаются в виде таблицы. А насчет схожего вопроса тут другое у меня проблема только в том что после завершение он переводит на страницу таблицы не смотря на то что все 3 кода срабатывают корректно

Comment: Я Вам показал, где код работает некорректно (хотя это и не влияет на активацию листа) - лишние реагирования на события. Предлагал закомментировать запрос, чтобы проверить, работает ли оставшаяся часть так, как нужно (естественно, без запроса). Всего не видно. Получается, что активируется книга с макросом. Может быть, срабатывают другие процедуры. Возможно, в первом макросе еще что-то есть. Проверьте на других машинах (вдруг Офис барахлит?)

Comment: Каждый кусок макроса я проверял по отдельности там все ок, на другой машине тоже проверял тоже самое. А у вас такой проблемы не было? Я имею ввиду после обновление запроса(именно из другого excel) он остается на той же странице?

Comment: Запросы не использую. Поставьте точку останова перед обновлением сводных и пройдитесь до завершения пошагово в ручном режиме  (по *F8*)

Comment: В пошаговым режиме все работает как надо. Для проверки добавил во второй макрос заполнение одной ячейки и запустил через кнопку. На нужную страницу не перевел но единицу добавил. Видимо это проблема самого excel проверю дома, спасибо за оптимизированный код)